# iPad SplitView Master View shows but with minor (and incorrect) variation

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller

I'm practicing development of a simple iPad Split View app (Stanford's Hegarty online class).  And everything works for the most part.  However, the Master side ('left side), although working in landscape mode looks a little different than what I expect it to as a 'popover' in portrait mode. The 'popover' covers the left side of the screen including the toolbar button item that triggered it where normally it should not cover that button.

Unfortunately I can't post images so I'll try my best to describe in more detail.  Normally the 'proper' popover will be hovering right below the bar item button that triggered it with a thick arrow-ish thingie (the 'anchor') pointing to the button and not covering that button.  The popover can be dismissed by clicking on that button again (or elsewhere on the screen).

What's happening to me, however, is that when I click the bar item button to show the popover, the resulting popover 'covers' the button and essentially fills up the left portion of the screen (the detail view is under it and most of it is showing) with its designated width (so, again, it doesn't cover the entire detail view).  The is no 'anchor' arrow pointing to the bar item button since it is obviously covering it instead. The popover is dismissed normally once I click anywhere else on the screen.

So why is my popover covering the button and not simply hovering under it with an 'anchor' pointing to it as it should?

I don't think it it makes much sense to post code at this point because I don't think it'll help and more importantly not sure what portion to post considering this might be a problem with how I wired it in the Builder.  Any thoughts  will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
Mo

Comment: Well, I finally decided (against my better judgement and as best practice to avoid future 'laziness') to actually download Hegarty's solution, compile and run it and, lo and behold, it behaves just like mine! SO: Here is my conclusion: The video I viewed from Hegarty was for iOS 5 AND actually running on an iPAD. I currently have iOS6 kit but targetting iOS 5 in my build preferences. I also am running this in the iPad simulator. So one or both of these are having an affect that distinguishes the behavior of the Master panel in the way described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its a change that came in IOS5.1

If you want the same behaviour you probably need to set the master up as a popover segue, from a toolbar button or similar in the detail view, and set the split view delegate to not show the master in portrait.

I'm on the move now but if you want any more info let me know and I'll try and get back to you later.